# KivyMd crashing on android

Tags: kivy

My workflow:

- In google colab:

> ```
> !pip install buildozer
> ```

> ```
> !pip install cython==0.29.19
> ```

> ```
> !sudo apt-get install -y \
>     python3-pip \
>     build-essential \
>     git \
>     python3 \
>     python3-dev \
>     ffmpeg \
>     libsdl2-dev \
>     libsdl2-image-dev \
>     libsdl2-mixer-dev \
>     libsdl2-ttf-dev \
>     libportmidi-dev \
>     libswscale-dev \
>     libavformat-dev \
>     libavcodec-dev \
>     zlib1g-dev
> ```

> ```
> !sudo apt-get install -y \
>     libgstreamer1.0 \
>     gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
>     gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
> ```

> ```
> !sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6
> ```

> ```
> !sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
> ```

> ```
> !buildozer init
> ```

- Edit the buildozer.spec file and change the lines:

> requirements=python3,kivy==2.0.0,pillow,kivymd,requests,schedule,urllib3,charset_normalizer,idna

> ```
> android.api = 32
> ```

- Run:

> ```
> !buildozer -v android debug
> ```

Deploy and run.

Result:

```
I/python:  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python:    File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 4, in <module>
I/python:    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivymd/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
I/python:    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivymd/font_definitions.py", line 10, in <module>
I/python:    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
I/python:    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/graphics/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
I/python:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.graphics.instructions'
```

How can I resolve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-17-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev

pip3 install --upgrade Cython==0.29.19

pip3 install --upgrade buildozer

buildozer init
```

Edit the buildozer.spec file and change the lines:

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.0.2,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow, # more packages ...

android.api = 33
```

Finally:

```
buildozer -v android debug
```